# How to represent a sigma sum when each step increases not just by 1?

Tags: measure-theory, summation

If the statement is like this:

Sum of $f(x)$ from $x=1$ to $x=n$ where each iteration $x$ is doubled ($x_{new}=2x_{old})$.

How to represent a statement like this in sigma notation? What is the strategy in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_k = 2x_{k-1}$, then you can quickly calculate that $x_k = 2^{k-1} x_1$, meaning that your sum is actually

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} x_1.$$

However, in general, if you have a sequence define by a recursive relation (for example, $a_1 = 5, a_2=4$ and $a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta a_{n-2}$) there is no accepted way to insert the recursive definition itself into the sigma notation. You can simply say $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_n,\text{ where }a_1 = 5, a_2=4\text{ and } a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta a_{n-2}$$

Comment: you mean $x_{k-1}$, right ?

Comment: I think you mean $x_1$ rather $x_k$ and $2^{k-1}$ rather than $2^k$

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1} = 2a_{n}$ so inductively $a_{n+1} = 2^na_1$ or alternatively $a_n = 2^{n-1}a_1$. So your sum is $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{n-1}a_1$.